# C# WPF child window (about window)

Tags: c#, wpf, childwindow

I have an application on C#/WPF that I`m developing ... I have a btn named `About` which should open a new window that contains details about the application or whatever I will put in it.

When I click the btn, a new window (about) opens, when I click again, while the new window (about) is opened another one is opened, how can I prevent this from happening, I also want the application to be disabled when the `About` window is opened and to be enabled when the `About` window is closed, Like most of the applications when about is clicked.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use the ShowDialog Method:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.showdialog.aspx

Code Sample:

```
// Instantiate window
AboutWindow aboutWindow = new AboutWindow();

// Show window modally
// NOTE: Returns only when window is closed
Nullable<bool> dialogResult = aboutWindow.ShowDialog();
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use ShowDialog() method instead of Show()

```
AboutWindow aboutWindow = new AboutWindow();
aboutWindow.ShowDialog();
```